# How to set up Windows Store App with WCF in potentially disconnected situation?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps

our setup is that we have a central Windows 2008 server with 3 distributed Windows 8.1 client machines.
We want to develop Windows Store Apps for the 3 client machines that both send and receive data to and from the central server. But there is a possibility that the connection to the server may be down at any point.

We want to ensure that:

- data collected by the client reliably gets to the server even if disconnected for a while
- the client app should continue to work/collect data locally if offline
- the client app should have access to the latest set of data retrieved from the server before it went offline.

I had thought that WCF could do this, and that MSMQ would be the best binding in this situation, but MSMQ isn't supported by Windows Store apps. The reasoning behind using a Windows Store app is that it's full screen and never loses focus.

Can anyone give me any advice on best way to do this? It doesn't have to use WCF - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anyone any idea on this? I'm struggling to get my head round this, and have gone for a desktop app in order to facilitate MSMQ. However, isn't it the case that if the connection to the server is down then the client can't access the service and the whole thing falls over anyway?